# How do I know when MovieClip placed on stage to finish play?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, movieclip

```
MovieClip(mcName).play();
MovieClip(mcName).addEventListener(??????, myStopFunction);
```

Or how differently you can learn about the end of play?

MovieClip is an external file and loaded into the swf as needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use two properties all MovieClips have:

`totalFrames - currentFrame`

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/MovieClip.html#currentFrame

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/MovieClip.html#totalFrames

Comment: What you need. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

When I have a custom animation and want to know when finishes I use to dispatch a custom event from the last frame of the animation. Usually an Event.COMPLETE will do.

In the last frame of the myAnimation MovieClip I do:

```
this.dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.COMPLETE));
stop();
```

Then in the main code I listen add listener to that evnet:

```
myAnimation.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, animationEndHandler);
```

Answer (score 1):

Almost like @daniel.sedlacek answer, but without timeline code :

```
var mc : MovieClip = new $TestMovieClip();          
mc.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function() : void {
    trace("COMPLETE");
});
mc.addFrameScript(mc.totalFrames-1, function() : void {
    mc.dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.COMPLETE));                
});
mc.play();
```

Answer (score 0):

Only check `currentFrame` and `totalFrames` is not enough for a MovieClip that has multiple scenes. You must also check if it is at the last scene.

```
function isAtLastFrame(mc:MovieClip):Boolean
{
  return currentScene.name == mc.scenes[mc.scenes.length - 1].name && currentFrame == currentScene.numFrames;
}
```